# Ошибка на странице "Инструменты Модератора"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

На странице ["Справка > Привилегии > Инструменты Модератора"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) в предложении "Однако, удаленные сообщения можно вернуть пор помощи голосов за возврат." - ошибка.
Должно быть "при помощи".

И еще странный дефект. Текст выше не отправлялся, пока не написал этот комментарий и не добавил рис. Что не так с текстом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Про сообщение при недостаточной длине текста можно почитать тут: [Непонятные сообщения системы для слишком короткого заголовка и текста](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/550)

Comment: Про правку: этой ошибки уже нет в исправленной версии, но её что-то никак не применят. [Опечатки на странице описания привилегий](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1605)

Comment: понятно. спасибо

Comment: хорошо, что напомнили.